# Fetching and grouping data by comparing time

Tags: mysql, sql

**Problem:**

I have 4 tables A,B,C and D.

Each table has identical fields: id,date,price.

I use inner join to show the price of each product A,B,C and D on x date using:

```
  SELECT
  products.A.date as date,
  products.A.price as A_Price,
  products.B.price as B_Price,
  products.C.price as C_Price,
  products.D.price as D_Price

  FROM products.A

  INNER JOIN products.B ON products.B.date = products.A.date
  INNER JOIN products.C ON products.C.date = products.A.date
  INNER JOIN products.D ON products.D.date = products.A.date;
```

However, I also would like to show what the prices of each product was after 1 hour of x date.

For example:

[image]

Comment: You have a row *exactly* one hour after each date/time?

Comment: Give a table data for clear view of question..I think you need to apply self join concept..

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes I do.

Comment: @Sumit I don't see how providing data makes it more clear but there are 4 tables with identical fields: id,date,price.

Comment: Ok..I try to solve..Wait..

Comment: @Sumit That's okay, I'll be fine if you propose a way of achieving it. I've look into self join but I don't think that would solve it.

Comment: @prCube.. Try this one..This is a example for two table..Same for 4 table..I got result..

Comment: I know you're resisting providing sample data. Please read this and reconsider. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query It's not clear, for example, how your date columns are populated.

Comment: @prCube.. I give you a solution..Pls check in answer block..

Comment: @Sumit I get this unusual error with table names although everything is right, nothing to do with you code. From the screenshots it looks fine, I'll test it later on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A1.date as ActualDate, A1.price as A_price, A2.price as A_afterOnehr,
B1.price as B_price, B2.price as B_afterOnehr
FROM productA A1 
INNER JOIN productA A2 ON date_add(A1.date, INTERVAL 1 hour) = A2.date
INNER JOIN productB B1 
ON A1.date=B1.date INNER JOIN productB B2
ON  date_add(B1.date, INTERVAL 1 hour) = B2.date
```

**This is table A and Same for B as example...**

[image]

**This is the output**

[image]